# NAN when evaluating exponential using pow but correct answer if I iterate?

Tags: c++, math, exponential

When using `pow()` from cmath library I get NaN but if I iterate for the length of the power, it works?

I am trying to evaluate `y=0.05*(1+-2.01655)^x` where `90 < x < 180` and I am receiving NaN when using `pow((1+-2.01655),x)` but iterating in a for loop achieves the correct answer? Worth noting excel also exhibits a similar issue (cannot evaluate raw form but can evaluate a segmented form).

```cpp
double var = -1.01655;
double final = 1;
for(int i=0 ; i<ceil(x); i++){
   final *= var;
}
final = 0.05 * final;
```

Comment: `std::cout << 0.05 * pow(1-2.01665, x) << std::endl;`, with a `double x;` set to 100, works perfectly fine for me. Helpful tip: try also showing a [mre] of the code that doesn't work for you, if you want to know why. Don't show some completely different code that does work. That's not going to be very helpful.

Comment: @Grant Dare  I’m not sure if you can use the `1+-2.01655` as a double base.   Is the `+-` a typo?

Comment: @manlaw: "1+-2.01655" is a perfectly cromulent mathematical expression in C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I’m not sure if +- yields a single double value.  In your example, you didn’t use `+-`, so your example is slightly different than the posted question.  I’m trying to understand why `pow((1+-2.01655, x )` would fail to work.  Has anyone reproduced a working example using the `+-` `exactly` as written?

Comment: Yes, @ManLaw, `std::cout << 0.05 * pow(1+-2.01665, x) << std::endl;` gives the same results, of course. Why wouldn't it? It's a simple expression, an addition of `1` and `-2.01665`. Feel free to try it yourself. Mathematically equivalent to subtracting one minus `2.01665`. There is no ambiguity, whatsoever.

Comment: Just ran the code.  Works for me, too.

Comment: Hi, I have identified the issue falls to when I don't round x.

Comment: Your loop is equivalent to `pow((1+-2.01655),ceil(x))`, not to `pow((1+-2.01655),x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a fractional exponent of a number implies an nth-root operation; for example `pow(2, 3.0 / 2.0) == sqrt(pow(2, 3))`.

Negative numbers often have imaginary roots. `std::pow` for doubles only handles reals. `1 - 2.01655` is, of course, negative, so your equation only has real results for integer values of x. I think you'll find that integer values of x generate a result and non-integer values are generating NaN. The reason your loop works is that you're calculating an integer power, not a fractional power.

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow); the section on error handling:

> If base is finite and negative and exp is finite and non-integer, a
>   domain error occurs and a range error may occur.

Comment: Hi, thank you that does appear to be the error. The value is not always an integer. How am I able to implement this solution where it will accept negative base and non integer powers?

Comment: @GrantDare `<complex>` has overloads for `std::pow` for complex numbers; if you use those you can generate the complex-number results of raising negative numbers to fractional powers. If you're not expecting to get imaginary numbers, though, then your equation might not be correct.

Comment: Accepted answer as it is the correct answer to my question. I modified my equation rather than the source.